# Blazor Wasm AOT build Precompiling failed

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have been trying to build my Blazor Wasm application with AOT turned on, but I get failed builds all the time. I have looked in the updates for the Nuget packages, but everything seems in order. I have looked all over the Web and I can't seem to find anything related, has anyone seen this before. It worked in net 6 and if I turn the AOT to false, it works.

All errors look the same and all relates to

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Precompiling failed for C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll with exit code 1. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Private.CoreLib.dl
l'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image addref System.Private.CoreLib[0000024D74966B70] (default ALC) -> C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net
7.0\linked\System.Private.CoreLib.dll[0000024D74964CB0]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib' (C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System
.Private.CoreLib.dll) [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Private.CoreLib.dll' has no debug directory. [
C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Priva
te.CoreLib.dll'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading assembly System.Private.CoreLib (0000024D74966B70) into domain System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (0000024D749
5A0C0) and ALC 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly System.Private.CoreLib[0000024D74966B70] added to ALC '(null)'[0000024D7495FB60], ref_count=1 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image addref System.Web.WebPages.Razor[0000024D74980D50] (default ALC) -> C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\
net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll[0000024D7497FE40]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor' (C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\Sys
tem.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll) [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor (0000024D74980D50) into domain System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (0000024D
7495A0C0) and ALC 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor[0000024D74980D50] added to ALC '(null)'[0000024D7495FB60], ref_count=1 [C:\Wor
k\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll' has no debug directory
. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading assembly System.Web.WebPages.Razor (0000024D74980D50) into domain System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (0000024D
7495A0C0) and ALC 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPag
es.Razor.dll [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Requesting loading reference 0 (of 7) of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages
.Razor.dll [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading reference 0 of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (defaul
t ALC), looking for mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Request to load mscorlib in alc 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll'. [C:\Work\D
ev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image addref mscorlib[0000024D74A0D610] (default ALC) -> C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\msc
orlib.dll[0000024D74A0B870]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Prepared to set up assembly 'mscorlib' (C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll) [C:\Wo
rk\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading assembly mscorlib (0000024D74A0D610) into domain System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (0000024D7495A0C0) and ALC
 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly mscorlib[0000024D74A0D610] added to ALC '(null)'[0000024D7495FB60], ref_count=1 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll' has no debug directory. [C:\Work\Dev\Gi
t\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll
'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly found with the filesystem probing logic: 'mscorlib'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Web.WebPages.Razor[0000024D74980D50] -> mscorlib[0000024D74A0D610]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git
\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Requesting loading reference 0 (of 9) of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll [C:\Wo
rk\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading reference 0 of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\mscorlib.dll (default ALC), looking f
or System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Request to load System.Private.CoreLib in alc 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly already loaded in the active ALC: 'System.Private.CoreLib'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Ref addref mscorlib[0000024D74A0D610] -> System.Private.CoreLib[0000024D74966B70]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Requesting loading reference 1 (of 7) of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages
.Razor.dll [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading reference 1 of C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (defaul
t ALC), looking for System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Request to load System.Web in alc 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader probing location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.dll'. [C:\Work
\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image addref System.Web[0000024D74A176B0] (default ALC) -> C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\S
ystem.Web.dll[0000024D74A13970]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Web' (C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.dll) [C
:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Loading assembly System.Web (0000024D74A176B0) into domain System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll (0000024D7495A0C0) and A
LC 0000024D7495FB60 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly System.Web[0000024D74A176B0] added to ALC '(null)'[0000024D7495FB60], ref_count=1 [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Image 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.dll' has no debug directory. [C:\Work\Dev\
Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.d
ll'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly found with the filesystem probing logic: 'System.Web'. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Mono: Assembly Ref addref System.Web.WebPages.Razor[0000024D74980D50] -> System.Web[0000024D74A176B0]: 2 [C:\Work\Dev\G
it\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Failed to load method 0x6000011 from 'C:\Appl\Compile\Blazor\obj\Release\net7.0\linked\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dl
l' due to Could not resolve type with token 0100001a from typeref (expected class 'System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider' in assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a') assembly:System.Web, V
ersion=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type:System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider member:(null). [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : Run with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug for more information. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk\7.0.0\Sdk\WasmApp.Native.targets(583,5): error : AOT of image System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll failed. [C:\Work\Dev\Git\Instruments\Blazor\Blazor.csproj]
```